# Jquery hide div when page scroll

Tags: jquery, css

i have fixed `div` in bottom of page with this css:

```
#bottomdiv {
    display:block;  
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    z-index:999;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

and i have footer `div` with `class="footergroup"`. now i need to hide  `<div id="bottomdiv">` using Jquery effect when page scroll Reached footer `<div class="footergroup">` AND show `<div id="bottomdiv">` when scroll go to top page.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the illusion of the footer to shrink and stick when you scroll up.

To find the scroll position relative to the bottom of the screen you need to subtract the viewport height from the scroll position: `$(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height()`. To make the transition smooth, also subtract the sticky footer's height.

Then you need to find your main footer's offset on the page. This is easily done using `$("#footer").offset()`.

And for the logic, you simply need to check whether your scroll position is `>=` your footer's offset from the top and use `hide()` accordingly.

All of this needs to be done on at least three occasions:

1. `document.load`
2. `window.resize`
3. `window.scroll`

**The markup:**

```
<html>
    <head><title>Sticky Footer</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="footergroup"></div>
        <div id="bottomdiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bottomdiv {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color: red;
}
#footergroup {
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
#padding {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('load scroll', stickyFooter);
$(window).on('resize', stickyFooter);

function stickyFooter()
{
    var $footer = $("#footergroup");
    var $stickyFooter = $("#bottomdiv");
    var footerOffsetTop = $footer.offset().top;
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    // Subtract your sticky footer's height for a more seamless transition.
    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop() + viewportHeight - $stickyFooter.outerHeight();

    // This is the real magic.
    if(scrollPosition >= footerOffsetTop)
    {
        $stickyFooter.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $stickyFooter.show();
    }
}
```

**[See this code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/bG3Zr/5/)**